# Light Image becomes dark while printing HTML page

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I have a plain light green image in my html page. But while printing the page content the image become dark green.

How to solve this issue. I want the exact light green image as output while printing.

Please help.

Comment: might be some color issue with your printer. try printing it on a pdf.

Comment: But the same template from another application (not a web page) working fine

Comment: Change the image format to png.

Comment: Need more info. Do you have any kind of color correction in use (either in the operating system, in the browser or in the printer driver)? If you do a print preview, does it look different from the display in the browser? And do other browsers have the same issue? Or when you load the page into a word processor?

Comment: While doing print preview it is same as what I can see in the browser window.The color difference happen when I take the print on a plastic card. I have tried to print it on an A4 paper from another printer and it working fine. I am using this site only in IE 9